# One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key Sensor in the item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to put items within the table and getting this error:
[image]

This is the objects.json file I am trying to insert into the db:

```
{
    "Sensors":{
        "L": [
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor1" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor1.txt"},
                "SampleRate": {"N": "1"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Orlando, FL"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor2" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor2.txt"},
                "SampleRate": {"N": "2"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Annapolis, MD"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor3" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor3.txt"},
                "SampleRate": {"N": "3"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Jacksonville, FL"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor4" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor4.txt"},
                "SampleRate": {"N": "4"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Balitimore, MD"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor5" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor5.txt"},
                "SampleRate": {"N": "5"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Washington DC"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor6" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor7" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor" }
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor8" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor9" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor10" },
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor11" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "11"},
                "Locations": {"S": "New York, NY"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor12" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "12"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Buffalo, NY"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor13" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "13"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Chicago, IL"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor14" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "14"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Trenton, NJ"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor15" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "15"},
                "Locations": {"S": "Los Angeles, CA"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor16" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "16"},
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "AltName": {"S": "Sensor-16"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor17" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "17"},
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "Date": {"S": "2022-09-11 15:00:00.000"}
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor18" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "18"},
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "Working": {"BOOL": false }
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor19" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "19"},
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "color": {"S": "Green" }
                }
            },
            { "M": {
                "Sensor": { "S": "Sensor20" },
                "SampleRate": {"N": "20"},
                "SensorDescription": { "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"},
                "Senor_type": {"S": "Type 2" }
                }
            }
        ]
    }   
}
```

Here is the table:

[image]

My eyes must be playing tricks on me because I can't see the issue or am I doing something else wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Apparently my description of the issue is too short so I am writing this sentence so I may post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the previous answer by hunterhacker is correct, `put-item` cannot be used to insert batches of items. Instead, to insert a batch of items we must use `batch-write-item` which will allow us insert up to 25 items per batch:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html

For your use-case, you will need to alter your JSON slightly to make it work. I have edited your example given which you can further refer to and use:

```
{
"Sensors": [
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor1"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "ImageFile": {
                    "S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor1.txt"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "1"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Orlando, FL"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor2"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "ImageFile": {
                    "S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor2.txt"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "2"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Annapolis, MD"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor3"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "ImageFile": {
                    "S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor3.txt"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "3"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Jacksonville, FL"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor4"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "ImageFile": {
                    "S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor4.txt"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "4"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Balitimore, MD"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor5"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "ImageFile": {
                    "S": "/Sensors/image/Sensor5.txt"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "5"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Washington DC"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor6"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor7"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor8"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor9"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor10"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor11"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "11"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "New York, NY"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor12"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "12"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Buffalo, NY"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor13"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "13"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Chicago, IL"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor14"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "14"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Trenton, NJ"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor15"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "15"
                },
                "Locations": {
                    "S": "Los Angeles, CA"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor16"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "16"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "AltName": {
                    "S": "Sensor-16"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor17"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "17"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "Date": {
                    "S": "2022-09-11 15:00:00.000"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor18"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "18"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "Working": {
                    "BOOL": false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor19"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "19"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "color": {
                    "S": "Green"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Sensor": {
                    "S": "Sensor20"
                },
                "SampleRate": {
                    "N": "20"
                },
                "SensorDescription": {
                    "S": "This is a description of a Sensor"
                },
                "Senor_type": {
                    "S": "Type 2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Now to insert this into your table, you can use the following `batch-write-item` command:

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item \
--request-items file://sensors.json \
--return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The `put-item` call takes a singular item and you’re trying to pass a list. You can see the docs and format definition at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html